# Changing git account on Xcode

Tags: swift, git, github

What I am trying to do is, I have a project that I got from someone on GitHub a little while ago. I just created my own GitHub account and wanted to link this app to my GitHub account so that I can use repositories and commit and push, etc. However in this app in the Xcode project in source control where it shows the master and history etc. it shows the name of the person who created the app originally and gave it to me. What I would like to do is to be able to link it to my account also so that when I commit something, he can't see it on his GitHub. I have already created a new repository on GitHub and have tried it out with a test app that I just made and it says my name under the source control side panel. I am not sure where to add a new remote and delete his for this project. I want to be able to commit and have it all set up on my account, so that he can't see my commits, etc.

What I have been doing before setting up GitHub was constantly duplicating the Xcode project whenever I wanted to add a new feature or edit something. I'm hoping this will help cut that step out?

Answer (score 0):

If having the original owner not see your new contributions to the code is important to you, then you could simply clone the new repository that you created on GitHub and copy the code from his repository into your new one manually.

If you do not mind your code being linked to his original code, you can fork the repository on GitHub and then clone it and begin working from there.

Doing either of these methods will give you the same situation that you had with your test app, your name and information will show up in xcode, and you will be able to make changes to the repos.

Comment: Thank you for your responce! How do I go about doing this? It's a pretty large application with quite a few pod files in it, etc.

Comment: Which method? @Jaqueline

Comment: The method where the original owner can't see my contributions to the code. I just added a little bit more info to my posts incase that gives some contextualization. @Mackenzie Craig

Comment: Sure, you can delete the pods and install them again with `pod install` later if you don't want to copy them, otherwise you can clone your empty repo on github using `git clone [url]` and then just copy the entire (ignore the `.git` folder) project into the new repository. Then you will be able to push to your new github repository without issue.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little confused. I made a personal repo on my Github account, I'm just not sure how to connect that to my project that was created by someone else. So that I can start using GitHub. I've never had a GitHub account except for today when I just created it

Comment: Is there a way that I can just swap in my account? I don't even see any of his account info. Just under the source control side panel it says his name and Master.

Comment: You can't just swap the account, because the repository you are currently working on it his. You need to use a repository that belongs to you. To do this, you need to clone the new repository (empty) that you created on github, and then copy his code into your repository. Doing this will basically give you a copy of what you were working on in his repository, but now it is under your github account and you can make changes separately.

Comment: I can still contact the person that gave it to me. Is there anyway that he is able to sign it over to me that way? Or is my only option to copy and paste it over? He gave me the file using Dropbox

Comment: If you can contact him and he has the repository on github, he can transfer it to your account. Just go to the settings page on the repository and scroll all the way down.

Comment: Ok so I can contact him and he can transfer it to me and all the changes and pushes I make, he won't be able to see?

Comment: If the repo is private, he will no longer have access to it, correct.

Comment: Ok I will let him now and get back to you if I have any more questions. Thank you so much for your help!